# (Mezzanine) Field missing from the form

Tags: django, mezzanine

I am starting with Mezzanine and at now I am building my first project with him (1.4.16 version).

I need add a field to Page model, but I dont want use EXTRA_MODEL_FIELDS (I prefer subclassing model method..).

Here are the steps I have followed:

1. I have created app called my_page and added it to top of INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py
2. I have created a model (called MyPage) inheriting from mezzanine.pages.models.Page
3. I have added a field called 'sidebar_description' to it
4. I have created and ran migration with South (the table is properly created in db)
5. I have created an admin.py to add my 'sidebar_description' to admin's fieldset

Now, if I access /admin I get this error: 'MyPageAdmin.fieldsets[0][1]['fields']' refers to field 'sidebar_content' that is missing from the form.

I have realized if I set a form inside MyPageAdmin class the error fades out, but I still dont get my 'sidebar_content' in admin fields.

Here is the code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d1cc75550937a7c0ae6c

Anyone can help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the code posted, you've unregister/registered the main Page model, rather than your MyPage model:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d1cc75550937a7c0ae6c#file-gistfile1-py-L21-L22

Replace Page with MyPage in those two lines.